# Selected time in Qualtrics JavaScript question lost when moving to next question and then back to the time question

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

In my Qualtrics questionnaire, I have a added a question where the participant should provide a time. This question uses JavaScript, see below:

```
    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/

    var Qbd = "input[id='QR~"+this.questionId+"']";
    
    jQuery("#" + this.questionId + " .InputText").hide();
    
    jQuery("#appt-time").on(" change", function() {
        
        jQuery(Qbd).val(jQuery("#appt-time").val()) ;
    
    });

});

Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/

});
```

I am new to Qualtrics, especially in combination with JavaScript. The function works partially: the participant can click on the resulting widget. Again, see below:

[image: Time widget]

However, when going to the next question and then back again to the time question, the previously filled in time is not available anymore:

[image]

How can I ensure that the previously selected time will still be visible/saved. Such that it will only change when a new value is explicitly chosen (clicking on the widget again and changing time, if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the value of #appt-time.

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnReady(function()
{
  /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is fully displayed*/

  var Qbd = "input[id='QR~"+this.questionId+"']";

  jQuery("#appt-time").val(jQuery(Qbd).val()); //line added

  jQuery("#" + this.questionId + " .InputText").hide();

  jQuery("#appt-time").on(" change", function() {
    
    jQuery(Qbd).val(jQuery("#appt-time").val()) ;

  });

});
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response! I added the line you mentioned, but unfortunately, the filled in time is still not remembered when moving to the next question and back to the time question again.

Is there maybe something else that I could have overlooked that you know of?

Comment: I don't know what widget you are using, but I would check the widget documentation for how to set an initial value.